# Send MVC actionresult to printer

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with an action:

```
SomeController/ActionToBePrinted
```

ActionToBePrinted() returns an html view.

This action is called from a normal mvc razor view when pressing a button - how would I go about sending the content of the view to a printer when the button is pressed?

Aloha,
Hugo

Comment: Modify your template so that `window.print()` fires off in the body. Then, on load, it will tell the browser that page should be printed.

Comment: I ended up opening following your tips. Opening the view in a new window and adding window.print() in the page - thanks a lot for the quick answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant send direct to the printer.

1. I suggest you to create a custom ActionResult, that returns a PDF file or something like that. [ASP.NET MVC Action Results and PDF Content](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/asp.net-mvc-action-results-and-pdf-content/)
2. You can show a html page as well and open the print dialog using javascript like this

`<a href="javascript:window.print()">Click to Print This Page</A>`

But always the user has to start the print process, you cant do this programmatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a GET request (e.g. use window.open() and pass in URL or use AJAX) and put the returned HTML contents into a new window.  Then use

[Window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print).  Then simply close the window when you are done.

You could tie this directly into a single view by adding something in the body, but I prefer to use JavaScript in these cases.  This keeps the design acting as a re-useable object or service that can be used across multiple views.  In other words, you setup the controller-model, but no view.  Instead, JavaScript steps in as the View.

Keep in mind that HTML is not a print format.  So if you need to control the layout, you should be using a print technology such as PDF.  XSLT provides an excellent means to create both HTML and PDF output using the same data, albeit it's a lot more work to create XSLT templates than it is to slap down  `window.print`

Personally, I have an MVC page acting as a service that takes URL parameters.  The page hooks into Adobe XSL-FO and uses the params to drive the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer!