# How to call class from a controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, iis, call

I want to all class from controller like this:

```
public void POSR(Item model)
{
    //some code... 
        db.SaveChanges();
        // class Printer
        Printer pr = new Printer();
        //call the method
        pr.PrintajNarudzbu(racunstavketemp);
        pr.mb();
    }
```

this works perfectly on VS 2012 platform, but on IIS it produce an inner server error 500.
any help, please.

Comment: Well, what's the error message? Do you have a global exception handler?

Comment: NO... I have trouble seeing the error message. The problem is in IIS settings... Whatever I tried it doesn't show it.

Comment: Add a Application_Error method to your Global.asax file, and get some information about what is happening. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562003/handling-all-exceptions-within-global-asax

Comment: it seems that you want to print the result, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297023/send-mvc-actionresult-to-printer

Comment: I resolved the server error. It doesn't show anymore in the console log. Is there any kind of tutorial how to print crystal report on the printer which is attached on the IIS side. When I run the web application from the VS it prints, but from the client side through IIS it doesn't.